how to calculate common elements between list column rows
Is it possible to calculate the number of common items in a list column, between a row and the previous row in the method chain?
My code below throws and error 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4],
    'list_column': [
        ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
        ['banana', 'cherry'],
        ['cherry', 'date', 'fig'],
        ['orange']
    ]
})

res = len(set(df.loc[1,'list_column']) & set(df.loc[0,'list_column']))
res

df=(df
     .assign(
         list_length=lambda x: x['list_column'].str.len(),
         nr_common=lambda x: (set(x['list_column']) & set(x['list_column'].shift(1))).len() 
         )
)

df


I would first convert all lists to sets, then use diff:
df.assign(sets=lambda d: d['list_column'].apply(set),
          common=lambda d: d['sets']-d['sets'].diff(),
          n_common=lambda d: d['common'].str.len(),
         )

Output:
   x              list_column                     sets            common  n_common
0  1  [apple, banana, cherry]  {apple, cherry, banana}               NaN       NaN
1  2         [banana, cherry]         {cherry, banana}  {banana, cherry}       2.0
2  3      [cherry, date, fig]      {date, cherry, fig}          {cherry}       1.0
3  4                 [orange]                 {orange}                {}       0.0

If you don't want the intermediates:
df.assign(n_common=lambda d: (s:=d['list_column'].apply(set)).sub(s.diff()).str.len())

Or with a custom function:
def common_set(s):
    s = s.apply(set)
    return [len(a&b) for a,b in zip(s, s.shift(fill_value=set()))]

df.assign(n_common=lambda d: common_set(d['list_common']))


Yes it is possible.  Here is one way to do it.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4],
    'list_column': [
        ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
        ['banana', 'cherry'],
        ['cherry', 'date', 'fig'],
        ['orange']
    ]
})


commonlst=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i==0:
        commonlst.append([])
    else:
        lister1=df.iloc[i]['list_column']
        lister2=df.iloc[i-1]['list_column']
        commonones=np.intersect1d(lister1, lister2)
        commonlst.append(commonones)
df['CommonOnes']=commonlst

outcountlst=[]
for j in range(len(df)):
    outcount=len(df.iloc[j]['CommonOnes'])
    outcountlst.append(outcount)
df['NumCommonOnes']=outcountlst
display(df)



This approach shifts more work to pandas while apply mainly uses Python. Depending on the real data it may be faster or slower:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4],
    'list_column': [
        ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
        ['banana', 'cherry'],
        ['cherry', 'date', 'fig'],
        ['orange']
    ]
})

df = df.explode('list_column')
df = pd.merge(df, df, left_on=['x', 'list_column'], right_on=[df['x'] - 1, 'list_column'])
del df['x']
df = df.groupby(by=['x_x', 'x_y']).agg('count')
print(df)

Prints:
         list_column
x_x x_y             
1   2              2
2   3              1

x_x and x_y are the 'x' values of the two compared rows. Rows without common items are omitted.

Here is a way with str.join() and str.get_dummies()
df['list_column'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().rolling(2,min_periods=1).sum().eq(2).sum(axis=1)

Output:
0    0
1    2
2    1
3    0


For Huge datasets, Use : from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'list_column': [
        ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
        ['banana', 'cherry'],
        ['cherry', 'date', 'fig'],
        ['orange']
    ]
})

# Initialize MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

# Transform the list_column to a binary matrix
binary_matrix = mlb.fit_transform(df['list_column'])
'''
binary_matrix :

[[1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
'''
# Shift the binary matrix
shifted_matrix = np.roll(binary_matrix, 1, axis=0)
'''
shifted_matrix :

[[0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0]]
'''
# Set the first row to 0 since it has no previous row
shifted_matrix[0, :] = 0  

# Calculate the number of common items
common_counts = (binary_matrix & shifted_matrix).sum(axis=1)

# Assign the result to the DataFrame
df['nr_common'] = common_counts

'''
   x              list_column  nr_common
0  1  [apple, banana, cherry]          0
1  2         [banana, cherry]          2
2  3      [cherry, date, fig]          1
3  4                 [orange]          0
'''

